# datatables.min.js how to sort records

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

I am using datatables.min.js to display my listing in wordpress. I want to display records such that latest entries should be display first (ORDER BY ID DESC). My query is correct but for some reasons it is not displaying as per my query order by clause (ORDER BY id DESC). It is displaying the oldest records first. Anybody can help how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables sorting is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862456/jquery-datatables-sorting-is-not-working)

Comment: Please post your DataTables initialization code and screenshot of how the table appears now. A link to your page would help as well, if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Default ordering (sorting) https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Solution :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#patientStoryLst").DataTable({
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength " : 5,
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sDom" : 'rt',
        "aoColumns": [{"bSortable": false }, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate answers. Besides, the question is not clear yet you're suggesting sorting all columns as numbers which may be incorrect for this case.

Comment: You shouldn't be answering if you're not sure that your answer is correct, there is little details in the question. Right now your answer looks like you've copied and pasted from somewhere else.